# Unable to set image when customizing Keyboard Extension buttons (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm trying to build a custom keyboard extension with Swift for iOS devices. But now I have some trouble when customizing Keyboard Extension buttons. Here are my codes:

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
      var qButton: UIButton = {
      var button = UIButton(type: .system)
      button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      button.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
      button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
      button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
      button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22, weight: .regular)
      button.setImage(UIImage(named: "q")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
      button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(keyPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

   var firstStackRow: UIStackView = {
        var firstStackRow = UIStackView()
        firstStackRow.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        firstStackRow.axis = .horizontal
        firstStackRow.distribution = .fillEqually
        firstStackRow.spacing = 6
        firstStackRow.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        return firstStackRow
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.addSubview(firstStackRow)
    firstStackRow.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    firstStackRow.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 3).isActive = true
    firstStackRow.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -3).isActive = true
    firstStackRow.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 10.5).isActive = true
    firstStackRow.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/4, constant: -12).isActive = true


    firstStackRow.addArrangedSubview(qButton)
    qButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstStackRow.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    qButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstStackRow.topAnchor).isActive = true


    }
}
```

But it seems the button 'q' is unable to display the image. Not sure what's wrong there. Any ideas would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using an ImageView when you can produce this button layout with code easily?

Comment: @excitedmicrobe Because I would like to make some customize. For example: setting the button with a Settings image.